# Unable to change Content type from quick edit view

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-type

I have a SharePOint library for which there are about 5 content types added. Some users do drag and drop files in the library and because of that the Content type value for these files is set to the default one.

When I go into Quick edit (added content type in the view), I am unable to change the set content type but when I do files>Edit properties, it does allow me to change the content type.

Is this the default behavior or is there something we can do allow users to change content type in the quick edit view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered here before:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/188506/14278

Quoting the answer:

> No other way around.
>
> Each content type has its own set of fields. Quick edit don't have the
>   flexibility to switch fields dynamically based on the selected content
>   type.